# PHP Reading currency quotes when "allow_url_fopen=0"

Tags: php, currency, remote-access, yahoo-finance

I need a fresh EURUSD quote to show my product prices in a website.

I'm trying to read the quote from Yahoo finance with the following code:

```
$eurUsd = 1.3700; // Default value 
$yahooUrl = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?f=l1&s=EURUSD=X';
$handle = fopen($yahooUrl, 'r');
if ($handle) {
    $result = fgetcsv($handle);
    fclose($handle);
    $eurUsd = $result[0];
}
```

This code works fine in my testing environment but not in my website since I have  "allow_url_fopen=0". I do not want to change it for a security reason.

The request I'm using returns a string like:

```
1.3715
```

Do you know how I can read the string in other way?

Do you know an alternative way to access the EURUSD quote?

**EDIT**

Thanks to Epik's code I tried to use curl, but without success with Yahoo.

Finally I rid off Yahoo and succeed with [Rate Exchange JSON/JSONP APIs](http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/)

**A working solution:**

```
$url = 'http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=EUR&to=USD';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$eurUsd = json_decode($result)->{'rate'};
```

Comment: Can you use the CURL library?

Comment: with [cURL()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)?

Comment: I don't know. Please post a code and I'll try it.

Comment: For the "Experts" who downvoted, Please explain??

Comment: I don't downvoted.. but I think its maybe about your comment: `Please post a code and I'll try it` - SO is not a "write me the code" side..but you should try it first and then come back here if you have a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?f=l1&s=EURUSD=X';
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Thank you Epik. Unfortunately I'm receiving "curl_setopt() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given" for all curl lines.

Comment: Forgot to add the curl_init(); function. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the fix. Now another problem appears. I have "open_basedir" set to "/nfs:/tmp:/usr/local:/etc/apache2/gs-bin" and this raises an error: "CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated". Any ideas?

Comment: Remove curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); or set it to false.